# What does the symbol ~ means when it's before a function?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I know that it represents a linear model relationship case because the docs, but when is this way? (see example below inside the sumarise_all function) how could I interpret it?

```
library(tidyverse)
# Example data
df <- tibble(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, NA), 
             col2 = c(NA, NA, "a", "b"))

df %>% summarise_all(~ sum(is.na(.)))
```

Comment: It is anonymous function ie. function created on the fly `function(x) sum(is.na(x))` i.e. a shorter, compact way to `function(x)`

Comment: literal meaning can be 'as a function of'

Comment: See `?summarize_all` for a little explanation. The `.funs` argument documentation describes "A function fun, a quosure style lambda `~ fun(.)` or a list of either form." Scrolling down, there is a little more explanation in the examples.

Comment: See also 9.2.2 in [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html) for more indepth explanation..

Comment: @MSR thanks a lot!!